# Vite rollup does not resolve alias only for electron files

Tags: electron, vite, alias, rollup

One more problem with path aliases. They work perfectly everywhere, but not for electron files.

In `vite.config.ts` I have `resolve: {alias: {"@": "/src"}}` and (part) of the project structure is:

```
D:/Project/src
  + electron/modules/A.ts
  + shared/B.ts
  + components/C.vue
  + services/D.ts
  + types/index.d.ts
```

Now `C.vue` and `D.ts` have `import whatever from "@/shared/B"` that works without problems.
Instead `A.ts` generate the `[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@/shared/B" from "D:/Project/src/electron/modules/A.ts".` error.

The strange thing is that in `A.ts` there is also a `import type {aType} from "@/types"` that is resolved without errors.

I tried to put an absolute path in the alias definition but nothing changes.

I'm working with vite 4.4.9 on Windows 11.

Thanks for your help!
mario

Answer (score -1):

Up, i also have this issue with my electron + vue 3 + typescript + vite project

EDIT: i found a solution, you may `npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-electron` and setup it into your `vite.config.js` like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import electron from 'vite-plugin-electron';
import { notBundle } from 'vite-plugin-electron/plugin';
import * as path from 'path';
import pkg from './package.json';

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    electron([
      {
        entry: 'src/electron/main.ts',
        onstart({ startup }) {
          startup();
        },
        vite: {
          build: {
            sourcemap: isDev,
            minify: !isDev,
            outDir: 'dist/src/electron',
            rollupOptions: {
              external: Object.keys(pkg?.dependencies ?? {}),
            },
          },
          plugins: [
            isDev && notBundle(),
          ],
          resolve: { // Resolve for main script
            alias: {
              '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        entry: 'src/electron/preload.ts',
        onstart({ reload }) {
          reload();
        },
        vite: {
          build: {
            sourcemap: isDev ? 'inline' : undefined,
            minify: !isDev,
            outDir: 'dist/src/electron',
            rollupOptions: {
              external: Object.keys(pkg?.dependencies ?? {}),
            },
          },
          plugins: [
            isDev && notBundle(),
          ],
          resolve: { // Resolve for preload script
            alias: {
              '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            },
          },
        },
      }
    ]),
  ],
  base: './',
  resolve: { // Resolve for renderer part
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '~js': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/core'),
      '~styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles'),
      '~fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/fonts'),
    },
  },
})
```

And then you may update your `tsconfig.node.json` like the following and reference it in your `tsconfig.json` :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts", "package.json", "src/electron"]
}
```

Then make sure to update your electron source code path, mine is at `src/electron` and output dist is `dist/src/electron`

Don't forget to update your package.json scripts like following :

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build && electron-builder",
  "preview": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build && electron ."
},
...
```